Future-Style settled options on stocks
I am trying to price future-style settled options on stocks (not on futures). I have researched about it but I can only find pricing for future-style settled options on futures, like in the following paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/fut.3990100402
Attempt for solution
My thought was to follow the idea about future-style settled options on futures. In such products, the premium is not paid up front, but it is settled on a daily basis. Thus, technically one does not need to discount the price. As a result, one can deduce the price of such products by multiplying the Black-Scholes on futures equation (otherwise known as Black's model) by $e^{rT}$ and one has:
$$P_{call}=FN(d_1)-XN(d_2)$$
So, with the same line of thinking, to calculate the price for options on stocks, one can take the normal Black-Scholes equation and multiply it by $e^{rT}$:
$$P_{call}=Se^{rT}N(d_1)-XN(d_2)$$
From this one can then calculate the greeks.
Is my thought correct? Can one deduce the future-style settled options on stocks like this?

Seems reasonable.

@nbbo2 Are you aware of any resources on this?

FX options are often traded with premium at maturity, so perhaps look there.
But in general, you're not changing the payoff at maturity, you're just changing the payment date of the premium. So another way to think of it is that you just need to adjust the premium for the time value of money (discounting).
So if it's easier, you can also just take the value calculated using the normal black Scholes formula, and adjust the result as follows: Premium deferred = premium x exp(r x t)
